# Central location for API URLs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

We are building a .NET Core/react web app which is integrating with multiple APIs so naturally, across the entire application, we are doing AJAX calls to retrieve data. We have a CI/CD environment set up and need the API URLs to be changed throughout the deployments based on the environment. In C#, we can use the appsettings.json for connection strings, custom settings, etc. and this can be replaced during deployments. What options exist out there for a similar approach on the JavaScript side? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Custom script that is run after deployment and replaces config files for the specific deployed environment. Can do that with poweshell